# Transition an Ember.js application from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ammap

How can I transition an Ember.js application from within a JavaScript function that is not part of a `Route` or `Controller`? Can I call something like `route.transitionTo()` or `controller.transitionToRoute()` using the `Ember.Application` instance directly?

What I'm trying to do is to integrate [amMap](http://www.ammap.com/) in an Ember.js application such that when an area on the map is clicked, the application is transitioned to the appropriate state.

[Here's an example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ghap/). When a continent is selected from the list, the continent is selected on the map. I want the inverse to also happen, what should I do in the following listeners:

```
map.addListener("homeButtonClicked", function () {
    // how can I transition to index from here?
    // similar to this.transitionTo("index") from a route or
    // this.transitionToRoute("index") from a controller
    alert("Transition to index");
});
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (e) {
    // how can I transition to continent from here?
    // similar to this.transitionTo("continent", id) from a route or
    // this.transitionToRoute("continent", id) from a controller
    alert("Transition to continent: " + e.mapObject.id);
});
```

Comment: did my answer work for you?  If so I'd appreciate the bounty.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah, but why do it in a global function when you can have more fun doing it the "ember way" :)

You're better off moving the map div into a template and creating an "IndexView" and adding your event handlers for the map view in the `didInsertElement()` method.  Here's a working emberjsbin:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EsAkAVE/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, that helped me towards the solution. I ended up wrapping the map in a component which fires an action when an area is clicked, and handling that action from the controller. As a bonus, I don't have a global variable for the map anymore.